# "Invalid field name(s) given in select_related" when searching one-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-views

my apologies as I am new to Django and this seems like a "Django 101" type problem, but I just can't seem to get it to work. I have a Django model for "Services" which has a related model for "Keywords" via a one-to-many relationship.  I'm simply trying to return the related keywords when I query the services, but when I run the view, I keep getting the error:

`Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'keyword'. Choices are: (none)`

My models are as follows:

```
from uuid import uuid4
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from blog.models import Tag, Category


class Service(models.Model):
    id_service = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    created_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    service_name = models.CharField(
        db_index=True, max_length=50, blank=False, null=False
    )
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    font_awesome_icon = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=30)
    service_image = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, null=True, upload_to="images/services", max_length=None
    )
    service_page_image = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, null=True, upload_to="images/services", max_length=None
    )
    service_description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    service_description_brief = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, blank=False, null=False
    )
    rank = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.service_name)
        super(Service, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.service_name

class ServiceKeyword(models.Model):
    id_servicekeywords = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False
    )
    created_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False, null=False)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.keyword
```

And the view that is throwing the error is:

```
import random
import markdown2
import geoip2.database
import datetime
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from services.models import Service, ServiceKeyword

class ServiceView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "services/service.jinja"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        servicename = self.kwargs["servicename"]
        service_list = Service.objects.select_related("keyword").order_by("rank")
        context["service_list"] = service_list
        context["faq_list"] = Post.objects.filter(categories__slug=servicename)
        for faq in context["faq_list"]:
            faq.content = markdown2.markdown(faq.content)
        # Get service with that slug and take from list
        service = service_list.filter(slug=servicename)[0]
        context["keyword_list"] = service.keyword.all().order_by("?")[7]
        context["service"] = service
        )

        return context
```

Any help from the pros would be greatly appreciated, as I've looked at the docs and spend an inordinate amount of time trying to fix. Thank you!

Comment: column `keyword` is a charfield, you need to `ForeignKey` column name in select_related

Comment: Thanks @NalinDobhal. I wasn't recognizing this distinction. With this information and the answer from Ibris I think it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a `related_name` on your field definition should solve your problem :

```
class ServiceKeyword(models.Model):
    ...
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name='keyword', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

You can find the documentation for the `related_name` [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: Thank you! This was causing headaches. I also had to use prefetch_related since it was a one-to-many and select_related still threw a ```"Choices are: (none)"``` , but the definition of a related_name did the trick. Thanks!